Shell Script: Reading excel sheet, update soap request with cells values and store the response - windows 10
I am trying to:-

read data from excel for specific column header and sheet
loop each row and make a soap call
create the soap request, update some tags with cells value
store the request
make the call soap
store the soap response
update the same excel sheet row cells with returned value from specific tags.

The xlsx file has such below table data
columnName columnName1 columnName2
-----------------------------------
1             A             100
2             B             200

my code as below without step 6 but it is not working
# Define the path to the XLSX file and the SOAP endpoint
$xlsxPath = "C:\Users\??\??.xlsx"
# Define the path of SOAP response folder
$responseFolderPath = "C:\Users\???\???"
# Define the path of SOAP endpoint
$soapEndpoint = "https://?????.???/????/ws"
# Define the excel sheet name
$sheetName = "??"

# Paybass the certitifcate
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

# Read the XLSX file
$data = Import-Excel -Path $xlsxPath -WorksheetName $sheetName -ImportColumns @("columnName1","columnName2") -NoHeader

# Iterate through each row of the data

    $data | ForEach-Object {

    # Read cells with specific headers (e.g., 'Header1', 'Header2')
    $value1 = $row.columnName1 
    $value2 = $row.columnName2
   # $value3 = $row.columnName

    # Construct the SOAP request with the new values
    $soapRequest = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:request xmlns:ns2="http://??/">

               <aa>$value1</aa>
               <bb>$value2</bb>

      </ns2:request>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
"@


# Store the XML request
 $requestPath = "C:\Users\path\request_$($row.RowNumber).xml"

 #$soapRequestContent = $soapRequest.Content

    $soapRequest | Out-File -FilePath $requestPath



# Iterate through each SOAP request file in the folder 


   $filename = $_.Name 

   $responseFile = Join-Path -Path $responseFolderPath -ChildPath "${filename}_response.xml" 

   # Send SOAP request using Invoke-WebRequest 

   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri soapEndpoint -Method POST -ContentType "text/xml" -Body (Get-Content $_.FullName) -OutFile $responseFile 

} 

I am getting the below error when i try to import the xlsx:
Import-Excel : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ImportColumns'. Cannot convert value
"columnName1" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:79
+ ... ath -WorksheetName $sheetName -ImportColumns @("columnName1")
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-Excel], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Import-Excel

